# What are the pros and cons of implementing webRTC?

Tags: webrtc

I would like to implement a video / audio call feature from a browser. The goal is to allow two users to communicate remotely without having to install a third part (when I say third part, I'm talking about a software or an extension on a browser).

I know WebRTC, which is very popular today and free. However, it is very difficult to implement and the documentation is difficult to understand (not very easy for a beginner).

Here is the official webRTC documentation, and honestly, where to start? https://webrtc.org/start/

If you have an experience about WebRTC, is it possible to share with positive or negative points? This would be very useful for the community.

Moreover, if you have experience with another library, I think it would be interesting to hear it.

Comment: This is a subjective question with no definitive answer.  If you want a chat app - google on building a chat app - maybe something like this: http://angularjs.chat/tutorials/angularjs-basic-chat-module/  if you get lost ask a  specific question in these forums

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to build webrtc based simple chat app. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_text_demo.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way to develop a call service in a website without the use of WebRTC today.

The alternatives are:

1. Use WebRTC
2. Use Flash (which is... dead)
3. Use a plugin (which is... dying as a mechanism in browsers)
4. Use an app you download (not exactly a service in a website)

Node.js is the way to go, but you will need to learn some new technology, especially when it comes to the backend.

The servers you will need are:
 1. The traditional web application server
 2. A signaling server (the one you plan on using Node.js for - you can use that for the web application server as well)
 3. A STUN/TURN server (for NAT traversal)
 4. Maybe a media server, depending on your use case

For some alternative open source and commercial products, you can check this [WebRTC Developer Tools Landscape](https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-developer-tools-landscape/)